# Is there an Esperanto movie canon?

Tags: culture

*Incubus* aside, what else is there that one should have seen? Just as there is a *baza legolisto*, is there a *baza vidolisto*? I'm not looking for movie recommendations, but a resource for movies that could be described as the "canon," if there is one.

Comment: The question talks about a "movie canon" but the "Evildea" example is a video blog, which is not exactly a "movie". Then again, AFAIK there are not many movies in Esperanto at all, so what exactly should be expected from the answers?

Comment: Well, if there isn't, can't you just answer "no"?

Comment: I'm not qualified tnough to give a concrete answer. I just wanted to clarify what exactly the question is about. I apologise if I may have sounded rude.

Comment: What I mean is, if there isn't an Esperanto movie canon, can't someone just answer "there are a lot of movies, but no one has so far defined a movie canon"?

Comment: And you didn't sound rude. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a somewhat opinion based answer, but anyway.

To me, making a good movie is one of the biggest challenges the Esperanto culture has. So far there are a couple of movies which are either not by Esperanto speakers or ... well ... bad. My main criteria of the quality of Esperanto culture is "Would Esperantists also read/watch/listen to it, if it was not in Esperanto?" And all the Esperanto movies I know of most Esperantists wouldn't bother to watch if they were not in Esperanto. Looking at music, this is different. I probably wouldn't know for example Martin Wiese if he didn't sing in Esperanto, but if I found his music in a different language by recommendation, I would listen to it.

The problem with movies as opposed to music, poetry, novels and stuff is, that it takes a lot of qualified people to make a good movie. To make good music, even one capable motivated person can be enough. Same for podcasts, poetry, novels. But for a good movie ... tough. Not only capable people but also equipment.

So to answer your question: No there isn't a movie canon, because there hardly are movies in Esperanto out there.

There was this attempt by the German Esperanto Association when they did a [short film contest](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxi_0YaBORM-RXX3HsGK5Hw). There are some quite good ones among them. Further there is the "Teo kaj amo" short movie contest by China radio internacia. Just search "teo kaj amo" on youtube.